# Getting Access Report Row Binding on Button Press

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report which has a button for each row.  Clicking this button should take you to a form with that items information on.  How do I get the currently selected rows binding?

E.g. Row 3 in the report is bound to "my_table" with a key of "14".  I want to get that data and then open a form which is bound to the same table row, so a user can make changes.

Thanks,

Fish

Answer (score 0):

You can open the form the same way you would open any form however you will need to add a hidden textbox on your report which contains the key value for the record in the table you want to edit. In the OnClick event:

`DoCmd.OpenForm "YourFormName", acNormal, , "TableKeyField = '" & YourReport.ReportField.Value & "'"`

Essentially you are just applying a filter to the form's recordset.